# How to optimize MySQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Please is there any way how to optimize this update query in MySql?

```
   UPDATE table1 t1 
   SET t1.column = 
   (SELECT MIN(t2.column) 
     FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    );
```

Both tables have around 250 000 records.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `column` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
 `code` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,    
 `column` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`code, `id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table1 (id)         
;
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are `id` the Primary Keys (in both tables)?

Comment: yes ..in **table1** is primary key just **id**, in **table2** there is composite primary key containing **id** which is foreign key from **table1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how I would do it :

create a temporary table to hold aggregated values

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_operation 
SELECT id, MIN(`column`) as cln FROM table2 GROUP BY id;
```

add index to temporary table for faster join to table 1 (can omit this step depending on data size)

```
ALTER TABLE tmp_operation ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id);
```

update with simple join. you can use left or inner join depending if you want to update columns to nulls)

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.`column` = tmp_operation.cln
INNER JOIN tmp_operation ON table1.id = tmp_operation.id;
```

drop temporary table after done

```
DROP TABLE tmp_operation;
```

Comment: Great! This is muuuuuch faster. Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by first grouping table `t2` and then use `JOIN` (this is similar to @frail's answer but without the temporary table):

```
UPDATE 
      table1 t1 
  JOIN
      ( SELECT id
             , MIN(column) AS min_column
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY id
      ) AS t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
SET t1.column = t2.min_column ;
```

An index at `table2`, on `(id, column)` would help performance.

Comment: @Daniel: and please tell us that you don't actually use those `table`, `column` names and they are just hidding your real sensible names.

Comment: Nice. I would be interested in seeing how the performance compares to frail's answer. This solution can't utilize an index for the JOIN, but it will still use a binary search, and if the result set isn't too large, this might be faster thanks to less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Add forign key in table2 of table1 primary key

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.column = t2.column
having MIN(t2.column)
```

[examples](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/)

Comment: thanx but I've got: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Please would you share the table structures/scripts?

Comment: You may use having clause in last time i.e having min(t2.column)

Comment: this query does not make any sence but thanx anyway :) ....... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having MIN(t2.column)' at line 5